# How can I show only the sale discount applied to a completed order

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2

I have two orders for the same product. One placed with a sale on the product enabled and the other with the same sale on the product disabled.

On the order details template for customers I have the following code

```
<table>
  {% for item in order.lineItems %}

    {% if item.purchasable.salesApplied|length or item.adjustments|length %}
      <tr>
        <th>Original Price</th>
        <td>{{ item.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endif %}

    {% if item.purchasable.salesApplied|length %}
      <tr>
        <th>{% for sale in item.purchasable.salesApplied %}{{ sale.name }}{% if not loop.last %} + {% endif %}{% endfor %}</th>
        <td>{{ item.saleAmount|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endif %}

    {% if item.adjustments|length %}
      {% for adjustment in item.adjustments %}
        <tr>
          <th>{{ adjustment.name }}</th>
          <td>{{ adjustment.amount|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <tr>
      <th>
        {% if item.purchasable.salesApplied|length or item.adjustments|length %}
          Total
        {% endif %}
      </th>
      <td>{{ item.total|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</td>
    </tr>

  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I get the following results:

When placed: **sale disabled**
Currently: **sale enabled**

> Original Price £150.00
>   25% off sale £0.00
>   Total £150.00

When placed: **sale enabled**
Currently: **sale enabled**

> Original Price £150.00
>   25% off sale  £47.50
>   Total £102.50

When placed: **sale disabled**
Currently: **sale disabled**

> £150.00

When placed: **sale enabled**
Currently: **sale disabled**

> £102.50

**item.purchasable.salesApplied** is reflecting the current sale status of the item rather than the status when the order was placed. Is there a way I can get the name and value of the actual sales that were applied at the time of purchase?